# equivalent of .copy() for functions

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

Let's assume I work with a collection of objects and I want to define one of their methods at creation. For example:

```
class Operator:
    def __init__(self, id, operation):
        self.id = id
        self.operation = operation

    def test(self, arg):
        print(self.operation(arg))


operators = []
for i in range(4):
    op = lambda x: x+i
    operators.append(Operator(i, op))

operators[0].test(5)
operators[1].test(5)
operators[2].test(5)
operators[3].test(5)
```

Here one could naively assume that we would get "5", "6", "7" and "8", but instead we only get 8s. I suppose this is because every time op is redefined it also gets redefined inside every Operator object.

I don't want that, I want each Operator to have its own operation method. I could do:

```
operators = []
ops = []
for i in range(4):
    ops.append(lambda x: x+i)
    operators.append(Operator(i, ops.pop()))
```

but it feels like a dirty hack.

Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: The reference to `i` inside your lambda is looked up when the function is actually called - and by the time that happens, the `for i` loop has long since finished - so the variable will have its value from the final iteration of the loop.  One solution is to write `lambda x,i=i: x+i`: this captures the current value of the variable (in the form of a default value for a parameter that won't actually be provided) at the time of definition.

Comment: "I could do: ... but it feels like a dirty hack." That way makes no difference. Did you try it?

Comment: @newacct: not this one specifically, but I tried other ugly hacks, some working, some other not. I gave this one as an example to explain what I though I understood about how things worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose this is because every time op is redefined it also gets
> redefined inside every Operator object.
>
> I don't want that, I want each Operator to have its own operation
> method.

The function objects in the `operation` fields of each `Operation` object are different. Every time you evaluate `lambda`, it creates a new function object. For example, `operators[0].operation is operators[1].operation` is false, and `id(operators[0].operation)`, `id(operators[1].operation)`, etc. are all different.

But Python functions capture outside variables by reference, and in this case, the four separate function objects all capture the same variable, `i`, and the state of that variable is shared between the functions and the outside scope it was captured from. So when `i` was changed in that outside scope, it can be seen by all the functions.

If you want each function to capture a different value as you iterate through the loop, there are several ways to achieve this.

One way is to use an optional parameter with a default argument, like this:

```
for i in range(4):
    op = lambda x, i=i: x+i
    operators.append(Operator(i, op))
```

Here, the function does not capture `i` in the outer scope. Rather, it has an optional parameter, also named `i` though it's independent of the `i` in the outer scope. (We name it the same so that the expression inside can use the same variable name.) The default argument of this optional parameter, is the value of the outer-scope `i` evaluated at the time the `lambda` is evaluated. Since it's the value that is remembered, and not a reference to the variable `i`, each function will remember a different value. When the function is called without a second argument, it will use the remembered default argument as the argument of the parameter `i` inside the function.

An uglier way is to put an immediately-executed lambda around the capture.

```
for i in range(4):
    operators.append((lambda i: Operator(i, lambda x: x+i))(i))
```

This works because the `i` in the execution of the outer lambda is different from the outer-scope `i`, and the `i` in the execution of the outer lambda only exists for the duration of the execution of that lambda, in which the value of its parameter `i` is passed in and never changed inside the lambda.

This can also be written as a list comprehension:

```
operators = [(lambda i: Operator(i, lambda x: x+i))(i) for i in range(4)]
```

or with `map()`:

```
operators = list(map(lambda i: Operator(i, lambda x: x+i), range(4)))
```